# Unable to test Google Cloud Endpoints on Java Server from Postman

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I deployed this repo to Google App Engine which is an example of Google Cloud Endpoints Java server. 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java

The app worked fine. I was able to test the REST API calls with Google API Explorer. However, I would like to test these REST API calls to this app using external tools such as Postman (A Chrome Extension which is a REST client) etc.

I have succeeded in retrieving the access token from Google. But when I made a call from Postman or from ordinary browser, the app kept rejecting the API call with "Invalid User" error. I tried logging the input User which returned null.

The below snippet is the REST API that I was trying to reach. The User which is the parameter of the method is retrieved from GoogleAppEngineAuthenticator in which I have no idea how it works.

```
/**
 * Provides the ability to query for a collection of Score entities.
 * 
 * @param limit
 *            maximum number of entries to return
 * @param order
 *            how the entries should be ordered
 * @param user
 *            object representing the current user making requests
 * @return the collection of Score entities
 * @throws OAuthRequestException
 *             if the token included in the request is invalid, the client
 *             ID included in the token is not in the list of allowed
 *             clientIds, or the audience included in the token is not in
 *             the list of allowed audiences.
 * @throws IOException
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "scores.list")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Score> list(@Nullable @Named("limit") String limit, @Nullable @Named("order") String order, User user)
        throws OAuthRequestException, IOException {
    System.out.println(user);
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
    Query query = pm.newQuery(Score.class);
    if (order != null) {
        if (order.equals(WHEN)) {
            query.setOrdering("played desc");
        } else if (order.equals(OUTCOME)) {
            query.setOrdering("outcome asc");
        }
    } else {
        query.setOrdering("played desc");
    }

    if (user != null) {
        query.setFilter("player == userParam");
        query.declareParameters("com.google.appengine.api.users.User userParam");
    } else {
        throw new OAuthRequestException("Invalid user.");
    }

    if (limit == null) {
        limit = DEFAULT_LIMIT;
    }
    query.setRange(0, new Long(limit));

    return (List<Score>) pm.newQuery(query).execute(user);
}
```

The reason I was trying to test this out externally is due to the fact that I need my existing mobile app to integrate with this Google Cloud App. Preferably, I will try not to use the client part of Google Cloud Endpoints but rather use the manual handling of Oauth 2.0 to minimise code restructuring.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Postman built-in OAuth 2.0 authorization for this purpose, but if you set the Authorization request header to your retrieved access token, it should work fine.

Key:

```
Authorization
```

Value:

```
Bearer access_token
```